# Problem with call WCF Service From local host to Server IIS

Tags: wcf, security

Hi All
I Have a service project that hosted it in local IIS and within this project i have a refrence to another service in an IIS on another server in this Domain but when i want calling this service I get an exception:

{System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The caller was not authenticated by the service.

How I Can Solve It?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Check with hosing by console.
2. Check Domain access for user or port restriction.
3. when you host then try checking whether it is generating wsdl by just typing http://.. in IE

Comment: Hi If I use this code I can use of that service:srv1.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "MyDomain";
                srv1.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "MyUserName";
                srv1.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "MyPass";
 It's intersting that me an My server are in same domain. Why I should login to domain again?